# What is reserve day in ODI cricket?

Tags: rules, cricket, icc, interruption

The match between [Sri Lanka vs West Indies](http://www.espncricinfo.com/tri-nation-west-indies-2013/engine/match/597927.html) in Tri-Nation Series was stopped calling it as a reserve day and it continued the next day (08-07-13).

What is meant by reserve day? And why ICC not following this for even some big matches? In what basis this rule will applicable? Is there any other matches was called off as a reserve day and continued on next day?

Answer (score 6):

> What is meant by reserve day?

From [Wikipedia - Limited overs cricket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limited_overs_cricket):

> Important one-day matches, international and domestic, often have two days set aside, the second day being a "reserve" day to allow more chance of the game being completed if a result is not possible on the first day (for instance if play is prevented or interrupted by rain).

> And why ICC not following this for even some big matches? In what basis this rule will applicable?

This depends on ICC and (if it's not a big tournament e.g. Tri-series etc) Cricket boards of playing countries. The reserve days are scheduled while scheduling the timetable of any tournament. For big tournaments numbers of days of the tournament are fixed as per their yearly schedule. And from the given days they schedule reserve days specially for latter stages (e.g. Quarter final, Semi final etc..). So that the match can be played again/resumed if the first day is interrupted by rain.