# Why can't a cricket match be played on other day in case of rain?

Tags: rules, cricket

As most outdoor sports can be played in rain , Cricket has a disadvantage. Shouldn't a match be played the next possible day in such cases ?

Answer (score 3):

In the case of important matches (e.g. semi-finals and finals of major tournaments), a [reserve day](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/2878/what-is-reserve-day-in-odi-cricket) is often scheduled which does exactly this.

However, in the case of a lot of other matches, it's just not practical. A high-level cricket match doesn't just involve the players, but the fans, the ground staff, security and policing as well. They can't all just be moved to the next day because it happened to rain. And for anything below full time professional matches, the players might not be able to turn up either.

Comment: But that's the case with every other sport, isn't it?

Comment: Maybe I'm misinterpreting your question - are you asking why there isn't an attempt to replay the match at all, or are you asking why the match isn't played the next day?

Comment: No no. You got it right. My question is "why can't the match be played/continued on the other day or some other solution to keep the interest going and removing the unfair factor by a margin